# how to avoid Can't mass-assign protected attributes issue from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

let's say, i've got 2 apps which use the same database(app), and i've got a field say: **cool**, so i want to use this field in first app but not in second. so how to avoid this error **Can't mass-assign protected attributes** without using attr_accessible in database(app) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand, but this is what I ususally do:

```
protected_attribute = params[:blog_post].delete(:protected_attribute)

@blog_post = BlogPost.new(params[:blog_post])
@blog_post.protected_attribute = protected_attribute
if @blog_post.save
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

It's ugly, but circumvents the mass-assign protection.

**Update:** You also have to remove the protected attribute from the params.

Comment: Right, you also have to remove the attribute from the params. I've updated my answer to reflect the changes.